# Issue with a CSS stylesheet not working

Tags: html, css

[On this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/subscribe.html) if you click CTRL+U, you'll be able to see the CSS and the HTML... I'm trying to create a page that doesn't conform to my usual style sheet so I'm trying embed the CSS in the HTML, and for some reason it's not working.

Relevant HTML code:

```
<HEAD> 
 <STYLE type="text/css"> 

subscribe{
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    margin:auto;
    }
 </STYLE> 
</HEAD>
```

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that, as well as the lack of a `.` before `subscribe`, that the opening tag of the `div` isn't actually closed?

Comment: Please always post the relevant HTML code here on SO. Otherwise, the question will have zero value to future generations because you will fix the problem in your page, and people reading the question later will have no chance to find out what the question was about.

Comment: why are we still hung with old HTML4 CAPS coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a . in front of the class name subscribe.

It should be this:

```
.subscribe{
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `.` before `subscribe`.